# UWP: Nested Custom Types with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: json, win-universal-app, datacontractjsonserializer

I am creating a nested custom type with primitive datatypes.
I am having a Web APi that returns the data in JSON.
using json2csharp.com, I am generating classes for the same.

I have decorated the primitive datatypes in all classes with DataMember and the types with DataContract.

I am using the following code for deserialization:

```
var resp = httpClient.GetAsync("http://ACTUAL_API_URI").Result;
var res = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
byte[] byteArr= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(res);
var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArr);
var deserializedObj= (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

I am not getting any exception. but the deserializedObj has null values for all the properties.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you provide api url? I guess problem in your `RootObject` class

Comment: Please find the Types used:
        [DataContract] public class MyNestedType1 { [DataMember] public int Id { get; set; } [DataMember] public string BD { get; set; }[DataMember] public string UD { get; set; } }  [DataContract] public class MyNestedType2 { [DataMember] public string Date { get; set; }[DataMember] public string U1 { get; set; } [DataMember] public string D1 { get; set; } } [DataContract] public class RootObject{[DataMember] public int Value { get; set; }[DataMember] public MyNestedType1 ObjectType1 { get; set; }[DataMember] public MyNestedType2 ObjectType2 { get; set; }
        }

Comment: Also, Created a simple service and a contract as below:

Comment: [DataContract]
public class NestedType1{  [DataMember] public int ID { get; set; } [DataMember] public string BD { get; set; } [DataMember] public string UD { get; set; }}[DataContract] public class NestedType2 {[DataMember] public string Date { get; set; } [DataMember] public string S1 { get; set; } [DataMember] public string S2 { get; set; }}[DataContract] public class SampleData{ [DataMember] public int Value { get;set; } [DataMember] public NestedType1 NestedTypeObject1 { get;set; }[DataMember] public NestedType2 NestedTypeObject2 { get; set;}}

Comment: Service as below:  public IEnumerable<SampleData> Get()
        {
            return new SampleData[] 
        {

            new SampleData()
            {
             Value=100,
             NestedTypeObject1 = new NestedType1 ()
             {
               ID=101,
               BD="Description#1",
               UD="Description#2"
             },
             NestedTypeObject2 = new NestedType2 ()
             {
              Date=DateTime.Now.ToString(),
              S1="S1 String",
              S2="S2 String"
             }
            }
        };
        }

Comment: can you give me a json data? you can insert to `pastebin` and give me url

Comment: Data returned from Service is as below:  [{"Value":100,"NestedTypeObject1":{"ID":101,"BD":"Description#1","UD":"Description#2"},"NestedTypeObject2":{"Date":"2/16/2016 7:07:01 PM","S1":"S1 String","S2":"S2 String"}}]

Comment: var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var resp = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost/MySampleService/api/Values/").Result;
                var res = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SampleData));
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(res);
                var ms = new MemoryStream(byteData);

                var deserializedObject = (SampleData)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

Comment: JSON in pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/15091333/

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple mistakes.

1. You returns collection of elements and try to deserialize one element instead collection

   ```
   public IEnumerable<SampleData> Get()
   {
       return new SampleData[]
       {
           new SampleData()
           {
               Value = 100,
               NestedTypeObject1 = new NestedType1()
               {
                   ID = 101,
                   BD = "Description#1",
                   UD = "Description#2"
               },
               NestedTypeObject2 = new NestedType2()
               {
                   Date = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                   S1 = "S1 String",
                   S2 = "S2 String"
               }
           }
       };
   }
   ```

   so you just change your code to

   ```
   var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<RootObject>));
   var deserializedObj= (List<RootObject>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
   ```
2. You have different model names between service side and client side, just you your `SampleData` model and all will be good. You must to rename `MyNestedType1` to `NestedTypeObject1` or add name to `DataContractAttribute`, e.g:

   ```
   [DataContract(Name = "NestedTypeObject1")]
   public class MyNestedType1
   {
       [DataMember]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string BD { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string UD { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   It belongs for property names too.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the return type of IEnumerable in the Get method of WebAPi was the crux. As it returns a collection, while deserializing "the collection of datatype" has to be used.  With this change, it was able to get the values. Property Name decoration was not required. It worked without it.